# segmentation fault(core dump created) in recvfrom

Tags: c, sockets, segmentation-fault, recvfrom

I was writing a simple C code to create a lisening socket. The code is teh following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>

void main() {
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    struct sockaddr_in client;
    int clientlen;
    char buf[1500];

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    memset((char *)&server, 0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server.sin_port = htons(9090);

    if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
        error("ERROR on binding");

    while(1) {
        bzero(buf, 1500);
        recvfrom(sock, buf, 1500-1, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &clientlen);
        printf("%s\n", buf);
        printf("%d - %s\n", client.sin_port, client.sin_addr.s_addr);
    }
    close(sock);
}
```

The code compile with no problem but when I connect to the server with a client using netcat:

```
nc -u 10.0.2.4 9090
```

and I send some message, the message are replied and then I get the error. DO someone knows why I get this behaviour?
Thank you.

Comment: `clientlen` must be initialized to the len of `client`. Currently it is uninitialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main issues here.  First, `clientlen` is expected to contain the size of the address structure before `recvfrom` is called, but it is uninitialized.  So set it as follows:

```
int clientlen = sizeof(client);
```

Second, you're using `%s` to print `client.sin_addr.s_addr` but that field is not a string.  You should use `inet_ntoa` to convert a `struct inaddr_t` to a string:

```
printf("%d - %s\n", ntohs(client.sin_port), inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr));
```

Comment: The issue with clientlen is solved, if I comment the second printf I get no error. Still I get errors if I want to print client port and address...